# My MNIST exercise: I get good accuracy but bad predictions with images I created myself

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist

I am trying to learn about Neural Nets, as first suggested exercise I am doing MNIST. After creating a model and running it on it's own, I decided to check if my model can actually classify images of digits I created myself. All classification hackathons, I am not even saying about actual job, will require it anyway.

Now, I want to say in advance, I do have experience with backend programming and C# with Java, but not Python and Neural Networks.

The code is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import mnist
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from PIL import Image
import glob

epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size=16

def CreateAndTrainModel(epochs, learning_rate, batch_size):
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    x_train, x_test = tf.cast(x_train/255.0, tf.float32), tf.cast(x_test/255.0, tf.float32)
    x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1,784)
    x_test = np.array(x_test).reshape(-1,784)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(784,input_dim=784))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(model, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, loss='mse', num_rounds=200,
                                      random_seed=1)

    return model

def GetData():
    file = open("CSV\data.csv", "r")
    data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
    file.close()
    return data

def getImageList():
    image_list = []
    for filename in glob.glob('Images/*.png'):  # assuming gif
        im = Image.open(filename)
        image_list.append(im)
    return image_list

def GetFileNameOnly(path):
    return path.filename.split('\\')[1].split('.')[0]

def GetCorrectAnswerByFilePath(path):
    key = GetFileNameOnly(path)
    answer = -1

    for dataValues in data:
        if (dataValues[0] == key):
            answer = dataValues[1]
    return answer

def ShowAllImages(image_list_length):
    for i in range(image_list_length):
        print(GetFileNameOnly(image_list[i]), GetCorrectAnswerByFilePath(image_list[i]))
        plt.imshow(image_list[i])
        plt.show()

def PredictImage(image):
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
    image = np.array(image).reshape(-1, 784)

    predicted_answer = np.argmax(model.predict(image.reshape(-1, 784)), 1)

    return predicted_answer

#Main
data = GetData()
model = CreateAndTrainModel(epochs, learning_rate, batch_size)

print(data)
image_list = getImageList()
image_list_length = (len(image_list))

for image in image_list:
    correct_answer = GetCorrectAnswerByFilePath(image)
    fileName = GetFileNameOnly(image)
    predicted_answer = PredictImage(image)
    print("File Name: ", fileName, "Predicted Answer", predicted_answer, "Actual answer", correct_answer)
```

Four images I created myself in Paint, like this:

[[image]][b.png]

Images are named: a.png(holds 4), b.png (holds 8), c.png (holds 1), d.png (holds 2).

And there is an excel file holding actual values for each filename.

**Now, the accuracy and loss values:**

**Epoch 10/10**

**3750/3750 [==============================] - 9s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1733 - accuracy: 0.9500**

**313/313 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1688 - accuracy: 0.9506**

However the actual predictions are weird, to say the least.

I tried many variations of batch size, epochs, layers number, neurons number in layers etc.
However, in most cases, the results are same either for all four cases, or in three among them, or two-vs-two and neither are correct.

**File Name:  a Predicted Answer [3] Actual answer 4**

**File Name:  b Predicted Answer [2] Actual answer 8**

**File Name:  c Predicted Answer [3] Actual answer 1**

**File Name:  d Predicted Answer [3] Actual answer 2**

Where I think the problem can be:

1. I know there is something called over-fitting, can it be the case?
   For now, I am doing pretty much "by the book", I do know that finding correct parameters for model is vital, but I have no experience to set those correctly.
2. Maybe there is something wrong with the code, and it won't give correct results with any parameters?
3. Or maybe MNIST is just not designed to be used this way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the inclusion of epoch data.  I read that to mean that you included your hand generated images in the training set to re-train the model.  Is that what you did?

I would not have suggested that you re-run the model with your hand generated images.  I would have taken the model you trained using the MNIST images and see what it predicts for those images.

I'd have to see [curves](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-the-bias-variance-trade-off/) to assess how you managed the bias-variance trade-off.

Comment: I trained the model, then used custom images just for prediction, I didn't retrain the model. At least that's what I have in mind. I posted last epoch values to show loss and accuracy

Comment: I added the line that should calculate "mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(" into the function "CreateAndTrainModel", but I get the following error: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100000,) into shape (10000,)". Also, does it come before calculating real predictions or afterwards?